# How to sql update two conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with the condition 'where'.
 
I want one more condition in this code:

```
$sql="UPDATE
            coursegrade
        SET 

            FirstExam='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstExam']) . "',
            SecondExam='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SecondExam']) . "',
            ThirdExam='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ThirdExam']) . "',
            Assignments='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Assignments']) . "',
            FinalExam='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FinalExam']) . "'
        WHERE 
            SID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SID'])  ;
```

Tell now I have no problem .. but the problem is that I don't know how to set the second condition.

```
CourseID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CourseID'])
```

I want the condition to be something like...

```
WHERE
SID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SID']) 
AND CourseID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CourseID'])
```

How could I do it?

Comment: What kind of error that you get?

Comment: What happens when you try the modified condition? Provide us the detail of the error. What is the type of `CourseID`?

Comment: i can't set the second condition
AND CourseID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CourseID'])

Comment: You missed a double quote and a dot  after the parentheses with $_POST['sid']

Comment: there is no problem with 
SID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SID'])  ;
just i wan't to add another condition .. how can i do this

Comment: just `echo $sql;` you'll see the problem. I explained it in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-87) syntax php will parse strings on a single line.

ie the rendered clause is:

```
"WHERE SID=19AND CourseID=45"
```

Basically you missed a space before

```
"AND CourseID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CourseID'])
```

or you could put quotes around the values

```
"SID='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SID']) . "'
AND CourseID='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CourseID'])."'"
```

Comment: YES ITS' WORK FIIIINE ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This is may help

```
WHERE
SID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SID']) 
OR CourseID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CourseID'])
```

or

```
WHERE
SID in (
  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SID']),
  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CourseID'])
)
```

its will work for INT value of SID and CourseID

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, and let me know if there is error message

```
$sql="UPDATE coursegrade
SET 
        FirstExam = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[' FirstExam ']) . "',
        SecondExam = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[' SecondExam ']) . "',
        ThirdExam = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[' ThirdExam ']) . "',
        Assignments = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[' Assignments ']) . "',
        FinalExam = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[' FinalExam ']) . "'
WHERE
        SID = ". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SID'])."
AND
        CourseID = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CourseID']) .";
```